# How to show address bar in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"https://facebook.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_Facebook loadRequest:requestObj];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

When it shows up I want the address bar to show up, like it does when I open the Safari app. I thought it was this line of code NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; but i guess not.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the url link to show up"?  You mean you want like an address bar that shows the URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'address bar' is not part of an `UIWebView` - you'll have to implement it separately.
See [here](http://normansoven.com/ios-webview/) or [here](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/22/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-2/) for examples.